# QML and C++: accessing members of exposed class

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I am creating a QML plotting component. The structure looks like this

```
Rectangle {
  id: canvas
  objectName: "myPlot"
  Rectangle {
    id: plot
    PlotArea { // this is my c++ QQuickItem
      id: pa
    }
    MouseArea {} // for handling interaction with the plot, like zooming
  }
}
```

`PlotArea` is a c++ QQuickItem.`PlotArea` has custom c++ members like an `XAxis` object (not visual) for computing e.g. ticks. How can I access properties or invokable functions from `XAxis` if XAxis is a `QObject`? If I register both with `qmlRegisterType`, can I e.g. do something like this `pa._xAxis.nameofmyinvokablefunction`?

Comment: A minimal example that we can run would really help. Especially at the end of the day when most people's brains are already fried from work. :)

Comment: XAxis is a QObject or what type is it?

Comment: Yes, a QObject. I guess it needs to be a QObject in order to access it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access an object from `QML` this must be a property, in the next part I show an example:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickItem>

class XAxis: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
};

class PlotArea : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(XAxis* axis READ axis WRITE setAxis NOTIFY axisChanged)
public:
    PlotArea(QQuickItem *parent=Q_NULLPTR):QQuickItem(parent){
        mAxis = new XAxis(this);
    }

    XAxis *axis() const    {
        return mAxis;
    }

    void setAxis(XAxis *ax){
        if(mAxis ==ax)
            return;
        mAxis->deleteLater();
        mAxis = ax;
        Q_EMIT axisChanged();
    }
    Q_SIGNAL void axisChanged();
private:
    XAxis *mAxis;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    qmlRegisterType<PlotArea>("com.eyllanesc.foo", 1, 0, "PlotArea");
    qmlRegisterType<XAxis>("com.eyllanesc.foo", 1, 0, "XAxis");
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import com.eyllanesc.foo 1.0
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Rectangle {
        PlotArea {
            id: plot
            Component.onCompleted: console.log(plot.axis)
        }

    }
}
```